# What are the exact Community 'view mode' device specifications?

Tags: community, community-builder, lightning-community

I have noticed a slight discrepancy between how our Community looks like in the 'mobile' option of the 'View Mode' in Community Builder and how it looks like in the 'mobile' options of various window resizer Chrome extensions and the 'Toogle Device' in Chrome Dev tools.

Are the exact device specifications for 'mobile' in the 'View Mode' for the Community Builder documented?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I received this response from Salesforce support:

> On my research, Salesforce Template-Driven Communities have been build
>   with a responsive design. So, depending on the size of the browser
>   window, the layout will be adjusted to fit best on the screen.
>
> For example:
>
> • The navigation menu, will show a "More" button on the right, if not
>   all menu items will fit within the width of the screen. • Or when you
>   resize your screen to the size of a mobile, the navigation menu will
>   collapse into a Hamburger icon on the left hand side of the screen. •
>   When you click on the icon, an overlay will slide in with a vertical
>   menu instead of the horizontal menu.
>
> Notes:
>
> • Depending on the size of the screen, a Dashboard will show multiple
>   columns and rows. • Dashboards on a Mobile will present all components
>   into one column. • As part of the responsive design, some components
>   and buttons might be hidden on smaller screens. • Chatter posts
>   created in Desktop mode can't be edited when in Browser mode.
>
> With the information in mind, there is no specific device
>   specification, it may be different on each type of mobile device and
>   size of the device. For reference you may also check our article about
>   "Community does not show all features in mobile browsers".
>   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Community-does-not-show-all-features-on-Mobile-browser&language=en_US&type=1